# How to generate multicolumn figures with individual captions

Tags: tables, floats, captions, tabularx, arrays

Excluding the header stuff, how would I create something exactly like the first document/image, but with side labels that show quantity of each item (second image)? I thought about using the subfloats method or a tabular method but its not quite what I am looking for. I am using the modified `svmono` class. Please and thank you.

[image]

[image]

My attempt is below. It is not coming out the way I want it to.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,sf,font=small]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty,font={sf,bf},skip=1pt}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{4}{X}} 
\begin{center}
\captionof{figure}{Beaker}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Beaker.png}
\end{center} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \underline{\hspace{1cm}}\\ 
            30 mL & \underline{\hspace{1cm}}\\ 
            \end{tabular} 
& \begin{center}
\captionof{figure}{Erlenmeyer Flask}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Erlenmeyer.png}
\end{center} & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \underline{\hspace{1cm}}\\ 
            30 mL & \underline{\hspace{1cm}}\\ 
            \end{tabular}\\ 
\end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Something like?  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{4}{X}}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image}
& \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}}
  30 mL & \underline{\hspace{1cm}}\\
  30 mL & \underline{\hspace{1cm}}\\
  \end{tabular}
& \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image}
& \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}}
  30 mL & \underline{\hspace{1cm}}\\
  30 mL & \underline{\hspace{1cm}}\\
  \end{tabular}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}`

Comment: @leandriis Yes, but how would I make it into the array like shown in the first image? Including the captions.

Comment: Is https://i.stack.imgur.com/yybBP.png closer to what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please also clarify: In the first image you added, there don't really seem to be uniform rows over all three columns. Do you want to keep this specific layout as well or do you want to place the images in columns and rows?

Comment: @leandriis Yes. The image you commented is more of what I would like to have. Also, I know that the figures are not in uniform rows, but the final document will have only 24 images instead. So, is it possible to like a 8 x 3 of the images? The provided answer has the captions centered, which I don't really want. Please and thank you.

Comment: @leandriis To summarize, I basically want the exact same formatting as the Glassware List, but with the added 30 mL ___ and 50 mL ____ stuff next to each figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the following is close to the desired layout. To avoid distorting the image, I'd recommend to either use the `width` or the `height` option instead of combining both.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries\sffamily #1}}
\newcommand{\myline}{\underline{\hspace{1.25cm}}}
\begin{document} 
\noindent
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{3}{@{}cX}} 
\mytitle{Beaker} & \mytitle{Erlenmeyer Flask} & \mytitle{Other glassware}\\
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Beaker.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular} 
& 
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Erlenmeyer.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular}
& 
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Erlenmeyer.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular}\\ 
\mytitle{Beaker} & \mytitle{Erlenmeyer Flask} & \mytitle{Other glassware}\\
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Beaker.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular} 
& 
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Erlenmeyer.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular}
& 
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Erlenmeyer.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular}\\ 
\mytitle{Beaker} & \mytitle{Erlenmeyer Flask} & \mytitle{Other glassware}\\
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Beaker.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular} 
& 
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Erlenmeyer.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular}
& 
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Erlenmeyer.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular}\\ 
\mytitle{Beaker} & \mytitle{Erlenmeyer Flask} & \mytitle{Other glassware}\\
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Beaker.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular} 
& 
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Erlenmeyer.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular}
& 
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm,valign=t]{Erlenmeyer.png}
 & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rl@{}} 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            30 mL & \myline\\ 
            \end{tabular}\\ 
\end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple case that images are placed in raster:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption, subfig}
    \captionsetup[table]{font=small, skip=1ex}

\newcommand\sfdata[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{rl<{\underline{\hspace{15mm}}}@{}}
                        #1
                      \end{tabular} 
                      }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=empty,font={small,sf,bf},skip=0pt}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.45\linewidth}
\caption*{General Chemistry Lab Glass List}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X X @{}}
    \toprule
\subfloat[image 1 title]
{
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}%
\sfdata{
    30 mL   &   \\
    30 mL   &   }
}
    &   \subfloat[image 2 title]
        {
        \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}%
        \sfdata{
            25 mL   &   \\
            25 mL   &   }
        }       \\
\subfloat[image 3 title]
{
\includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}%
\sfdata{
    100 mL   &   \\
    100 mL   &   }
}
    &   \subfloat[image 4 title]
        {
        \includegraphics[valign=t]{example-image-duck}%
        \sfdata{
            50 mL   &   \\
            50 mL   &   }
        }       \\        
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]